# Golang yaml.v2 marshals an array as a sequence

Tags: go, yaml, marshalling, unmarshalling

Given the following YAML:

```
array.test: ["val1", "val2", "val3"]
```

I Unmarshal it using gopkg.in/yaml.v2 into a `map[string]interface{}`. Then I get a single key whose value is an array of 3 values.

When I then Marshal it again to YAML, the resulting YAML looks like this:

```
array.test:
- val1
- val2
- val3
```

The array was actually marshaled as a sequence instead of an array.

This is the entire GoLang code:

```
func main(){
    data := `array.test: ["val1", "val2", "val3"]`
    conf := make(map[string]interface{})
    yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(data), conf)

    data2, _ := yaml.Marshal(conf)
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", string(data2))
}
```

How can I overcome this issue?

Comment: Both YAML's you show have sequences, and are semantically equivalent. Your first YAML uses a flow-style sequence and the second example uses a block-style sequence. There is no such thing as an array in YAML.

Comment: OK so is there any way to force the marshaller to use flow-style, without having to define a specific struct?

Comment: No. There are libraries that allow all-flow-style, all-block-style, or outmost-collection-flow-style, but not yaml.v2

Comment: Can you recommend one?

Answer (score 5):

This one helped me in the same case as you.

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "log"

        "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
)

var data = `
a: Easy!
b:
c: 2
d.test: ["d1", "d2"]
`

// Note: struct fields must be public in order for unmarshal to
// correctly populate the data.
type T struct {
    A string
    B struct {
            RenamedC int   `yaml:"c"`
            DTest        []string `yaml:"d.test,flow"`
    }
}

func main() {
    // if we use struct containing yaml encoding for yaml formated string 
    t := T{}

    err := yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &t)
    if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("error: %v", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("--- t after unmarshal:\n%v\n\n", t)

    d, err := yaml.Marshal(&t)
    if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("error: %v", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("--- t after marshal:\n%s\n\n", string(d))
}
```

Ref: https://github.com/go-yaml/yaml

Comment: thanks for the answer but this is not my case. I'm trying to marshal a map, not a predefined struct.

Comment: @Forepick: As every answer indicates, using a struct is the only way to do what you're asking.

Comment: @Shudipta Thank you for the "struct fields must be public" comment; this helped me solve a similar issue!

Answer (score 2):

*Flow* tag allows you to choose the representation of an array in yaml

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
)

type Conf struct {
    Test []string `yaml:"array.test,flow"`
}

func main(){
    data := `array.test: ["val1", "val2", "val3"]`
    var conf Conf
    yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &conf)

    data2, _ := yaml.Marshal(conf)
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", string(data2))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`flow`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/yaml.v2#Marshal) in struct field tag format, to indicate you desire this behavior. But, of course, this requires unmarshaling to a struct, not to a map.